# No me guarda la fecha en el useState - DateTimePickerModal - React Native

Tags: date, react-native, modal, datepicker

Intento guardar la fecha dentro de:

```
const [eventDate, setEventDate] = useState("");
```

Estoy utilizando:

```
import DateTimePickerModal from "react-native-modal-datetime-picker";

const handleConfirm = date => {
    var fecha = moment(date).format("DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss");
    console.log(fecha);
    () => setEventDate(fecha);
    hideDatePicker();
  };
```

La variable fecha por consola me devuelve:

```
27/02/2020 10:35:58
```

Pero esta no se almacena dentro de **EventDate**.

dejo un fragmento de codigo más amplio:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import {
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  ScrollView,
  Alert,
  Dimensions,
  Picker
} from "react-native";
import {
  Icon,
  Avatar,
  Image,
  Input,
  Button,
  Card,
  CheckBox,
  Text
} from "react-native-elements";
import * as ImagePicker from "expo-image-picker";
import * as Permissions from "expo-permissions";
import moment from "moment";
import RNDateTimePicker from "@react-native-community/datetimepicker";

const widthScreen = Dimensions.get("window").width;

export default function AddEventForm(props) {
  const { toastRef, setIsLoading, navigation } = props;
  const [imagesSelected, setImagesSelected] = useState([]);
  const [eventName, setEventName] = useState("");
  const [eventDescription, setEventDescription] = useState("");
  const [eventDate, setEventDate] = useState("");
  const [isDateTimePickerVisible, setIsDateTimePickerVisible] = useState(false);
  const [eventType, setEventType] = useState("");
  const [eventStatus, setEventStatus] = useState("");
  const [eventCapacity, setEventCapacity] = useState("");
  const [eventMapUbication, setEventMapUbication] = useState("");
  const [eventCountry, setEventCountry] = useState("");
  const [eventState, setEventState] = useState("");
  const [eventStreet, setEventStreet] = useState("");
  const [eventPostalCode, setEventPostalCode] = useState("");
  const [date, setDate] = useState(new Date().getDate());
  const [mode, setMode] = useState("date");
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

  const testeoVariables = () => {
    console.log("eventName " + eventName);
    console.log("eventDescription " + eventDescription);
    console.log("eventCapacity " + eventCapacity);
    console.log("eventMapUbication " + eventMapUbication);
    console.log("eventCountry " + eventCountry);
    console.log("eventState " + eventState);
    console.log("eventStreet " + eventStreet);
    console.log("eventPostalCode " + eventPostalCode);
    console.log("eventdate " + eventDate);
    console.log("eventype " + eventType);
  };

  return (
    <ScrollView>
      <ImageEventFeatured imageEvent={imagesSelected[0]} />
      <UploadImage
        imagesSelected={imagesSelected}
        setImagesSelected={setImagesSelected}
        toastRef={toastRef}
      />
      <FormAdd
        setEventName={setEventName}
        setEventDescription={setEventDescription}
        setEventDate={setEventDate}
        eventDate={eventDate}
        setEventType={setEventType}
        eventType={eventType}
        setEventStatus={setEventStatus}
        setEventCapacity={setEventCapacity}
        setEventMapUbication={setEventMapUbication}
        setEventCountry={setEventCountry}
        setEventState={setEventState}
        setEventStreet={setEventStreet}
        setEventPostalCode={setEventPostalCode}
        date={date}
        mode={mode}
        show={show}
        setDate={setDate}
        setShow={setShow}
        setMode={setMode}
        testeoVariables={testeoVariables}
      />
    </ScrollView>
  );
}

function FormAdd(props) {

  const onChange = (event, selectedDate) => {
    const currentDate = selectedDate || date;
    setDate(currentDate);
    console.log(selectedDate);
    setShow(Platform.OS === "ios" ? true : false);
  };

  const showMode = currentMode => {
    setShow(true);
    setMode(currentMode);
  };

  const showDatepicker = () => {
    showMode("date");
  };

  const showTimepicker = () => {
    showMode("time");
  };

  const {
    setEventName,
    setEventDescription,
    setEventDate,
    eventDate,
    setEventType,
    eventType,
    setEventStatus,
    setEventCapacity,
    setEventMapUbication,
    setEventCountry,
    setEventState,
    setEventStreet,
    setEventPostalCode,
    setDate,
    setShow,
    setMode,
    date,
    mode,
    show,
    testeoVariables
  } = props;

  return (
    <View style={styles.viewForm}>
      <Card>
        <View>
          <Text style={styles.txtHeadline} h4>
            Información del evento
          </Text>
          <Input
            placeholder="Nombre del evento"
            containerStyle={styles.input}
            onChange={e => setEventName(e.nativeEvent.text)}
          />
          <Input
            placeholder="Descripción"
            containerStyle={styles.textArea}
            multiline={true}
            onChange={e => setEventDescription(e.nativeEvent.text)}
          />
        </View>
        <View>
          <View>
            <Button onPress={showDatepicker} title="Show date picker!" />
          </View>
          {show && (
            <RNDateTimePicker
              value={new Date()}
              mode="date"
              onChange={onChange}
            />
          )}
        </View>
      </Card>
      <Card>
        <View style={styles.containerEventType}>
          <Text style={styles.txtHeadline} h4>
            Tipo de evento
          </Text>
          <Picker
            mode={"dropdown"}
            selectedValue={eventType == null ? "java" : eventType}
            style={{ height: 50, width: 100 }}
            onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => setEventType(itemValue)}
          >
            <Picker.Item label="Java" value="java" />
            <Picker.Item label="JavaScript" value="js" />
          </Picker>
        </View>
      </Card>
      <Card>
        <Text style={styles.txtHeadline} h4>
          Ubicación y capacidad
        </Text>
        <Input
          placeholder="Aforo del evento"
          containerStyle={styles.input}
          keyboardType="numeric"
          maxLength={1000000}
          onChange={e => setEventCapacity(e.nativeEvent.text)}
        />
        <Input
          placeholder="Ubicación en el mapa"
          rightIcon={{
            type: "material-community",
            name: "google-maps",
            color: "#c2c2c2",
            onPress: () => console.log("Seleccione la ubicación")
          }}
          containerStyle={styles.input}
          onChange={e => setEventMapUbication(e.nativeEvent.text)}
        />
        <Input
          placeholder="País"
          containerStyle={styles.input}
          onChange={e => setEventCountry(e.nativeEvent.text)}
        />
        <Input
          placeholder="Municipio"
          containerStyle={styles.input}
          onChange={e => setEventState(e.nativeEvent.text)}
        />
        <Input
          placeholder="Calle"
          containerStyle={styles.input}
          onChange={e => setEventStreet(e.nativeEvent.text)}
        />
        <Input
          placeholder="Código Postal"
          containerStyle={styles.input}
          onChange={e => setEventPostalCode(e.nativeEvent.text)}
        />
      </Card>
      <Button title="Crear evento" onPress={testeoVariables} />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: agrega todo el codigo del componente

Answer (score 1):

Debes settear la variable para enviarla al Form

```
const handleConfirm = date => {
    setEventDate(moment(date).format("DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss"));
    hideDatePicker();
  };
```

esto funciono para mi

Answer (score 0):

No se si todavía te sirva, pero es probable que tu hook no tenga el formato de fecha intenta declararlo así:

```
const[eventDate, seteventDate] = useState(new Date())
```